# Python/sqlite: get column values as a list/tuple from rows where other columns have certain values

Tags: python, sqlite

I have a sqlite table with 4 columns, say: id, pagenr, x1, y1.
I need to get the y1 column values as a list/tuple, but only from rows where pagenr and x1 have certain values. Help much appriciated. NB: I am using python 2.6.

Comment: I have done : c.execute('SELECT x1 FROM my_table WHERE pagenr = 2 AND x1 = 10').fetchall() but i haven't been able to get the results as list/tuple.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This code using the sqlite3 module should fetch the rows of the result from the query into the `output` list:

```
conn = sqlite3.connect('database.db')
c = conn.cursor()
c.execute('select y1 from table where pagenr=? and x1=?',
(pagenr_value, x1_value))
output = c.fetchall()
```

Comment: The result of the fetchall method is a list of tuples. If you are interested in the first value you could do OutputList[0][0]

Comment: A tuple with a single item is always constructed by following a value with a comma. If you prefer to get a list of values you could use a list comprehension: [x[0] for x in TupleList]